# About set operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $A,B$ be countable unions $A:=\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and $B:=\cup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$. I am reading a book and it says $(A-B)\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^\infty (A_i-B_i)$. It is probably trivial but I don't understand why?

My attempt: Let $x\in A-B$. If I can show that $x\in A_i-B_i$ for some $i$, then I am done. Since $x\in A-B$, we have $x\in A$ which means $x\in A_i$ for some $i$. Now $x\in A-B$ again implies $x\in A_i-B_j$ for some $j$. Is that the idea here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but not quite right. $x\in A-B$ means that $x\in A$, but $x\notin B$. By definition of $A$ and $B$ this means that $x\in A_i$ for some $i$, and $x\notin B_j$ for all $j$. In particular this means that $x\in (A_i-B_i)\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (A_k-B_k)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the identity $A\setminus B=A\cap B^C$, so we have that
$$
A\setminus B=\Big(\bigcup A_i\Big)\cap \Big(\bigcup_j B_j\Big)^C
$$
using the De Morgan's law
$$
=\Big(\bigcup A_i\Big)\cap \Big(\bigcap B_j^C\Big)=\bigcup_i \Big(
A_i\cap\bigcap_j B_j^C
\Big)\subset 
\bigcup_i \Big(
A_i\cap B_i^C
\Big)=\bigcup_i (A_i\setminus B_i)
$$
as desired.

Comment: of course assuming you've proved de Morgan's laws for infinite unions.